# What are workable/straightforward methods for using external game controllers (bluetooth, USB) with the Android platform?

Tags: bluetooth, usb-peripherals, usb-host-mode

I own an Archos 43 IT running Android 2.2.  It is my understanding that the Archos devices in this product line support USB Host and Bluetooth.

**What are workable/straightforward methods for using external game controllers with the Android platform?**

I am aware of the [WiiMoteController](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=672884) project, and the capability of hooking up a Wii Classic Controller to a Wii Controller via bluetooth for emulator usage such as [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dTohnRxG4Sw).

The thing is that I don't already own any Wii controllers and it seems like a waste to go out and get those controllers if I already own several [Logitech Dual Action USB](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/gaming/controllers/devices/288) gamepads, and could use those instead.

Comment: Voted to close -- "What's out there?" isn't a real question.

Comment: I have changed the wording to be less subjective.

Comment: "Best" is still pretty subjective.

Comment: I changed "best" to "workable/straightforward".  I just want to see solutions with as few steps as possible.

Comment: This question is more an open question than an straightforward one. But I think it has a great value, should stay and become community-wiki when more good quality answers show up.

Comment: @Zoot: Better, although the whole "would anyone like to share their experiences" still runs afoul of the guidelines.

Comment: @Al Everett The "share your experiences" paragraph has been removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best option (albeit a rather pricey one) appears to be the [iControlPad](http://icontrolpad.com/).  It was originally designed for use with an iPhone but now uses bluetooth to communicate with all bluetooth-enabled devices.  It sounds like developers plan on supporting it, but I'm not sure how well it will work with current games.

EDIT:  I recently became aware of another bluetooth gamepad that caters specifically to smartphones.  It's called the Bluetooth Game Gripper.  There is an Andoinica article about it [here](http://androinica.com/2011/02/game-gripper-will-provide-gaming-keys-to-touchscreen-devices-via-bluetooth/), and the kickstarter project is [here](http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/bossgizmo/new-bluetooth-game-gripper-a-game-pad-for-your-pho).  However, it doesn't appear that the maker has garnered enough VC to get the project off the ground, so I'm not sure of the current status.