# How to use Generic USB Joysticks in Android via OTG?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, usb, usb-on-the-go, game-controllers

I have a generic USB game controller (looks like a PS2 controller) and I just got my ordered USB OTG cable. So far keyboard and mouse work, however, when I insert the gamepad, I can't seem to make it work. Any thoughts? What can I do to make it work?

Some details about the phone:

- Rooted
- [Unlocked bootloader](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1398910)
- [Ice Cream Sandwich 4.0.4](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1705255)

Comment: There's a few previous questions on using gamepads (USB and otherwise) that could maybe help you out: [ICS and support of gamepad/controller devices](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20009/), and [What are workable/straightforward methods for using external game controllers (bluetooth, USB) with the Android platform?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3569/)

Comment: You gave "some details about the phone", but not what phone it is. USB gamepads just worked in all my devices. Probably your phone lacks the necessary drivers, but we need to know which phone to tell.

Answer (score 1):

You need to root your device. 
Also, you need to have and install the following:

Software (APK)
1. USB/BT Joy Center

Hardware 
1. USB hub with power capability
2. your generic gamepad
3. USB OTG

1. After the installation of the APK Insert your hub with power capability (some tablets and phones cant give enough power to the joystick).
2. When the USB hub lights up it is detected by the tab, all you need to do is plug your generic gamepad.
3. Now open USB/BT Joy Center this software will automatically detect your gamepad.
4. (trouble shooting) when your device is not detected. Restart your device with all the hardware connected.
5. When your tab is already open, try reopening USB/BT Joy Center. I think this should do the trick.